# Export users with credential in keycloak with Admin Console API

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, keycloak, credentials

How to export users with credential in keycloak using Admin Console API
I used this endpoint but it not contains the credential of users
`curl -X GET https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/users`

## this is the result of endpoint not contains the credential

```
 {
    "id": "dbede89b-dbf8-4b4b-84a6-da7b6c1877e3",
    "createdTimestamp": 1607591201217,
    "username": "admin",
    "enabled": true,
    "totp": false,
    "emailVerified": false,
    "disableableCredentialTypes": [],
    "requiredActions": [],
    "notBefore": 0,
    "access": {
        "manageGroupMembership": true,
        "view": true,
        "mapRoles": true,
        "impersonate": true,
        "manage": true
    }
},
```

How can I recover users with credential ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, using that endpoint *alone* will not return you back the user credentials. You can, however, import the users with the credentials using the endpoint:

```
PUT https://$KEYCLOAK_IP/auth/admin/realms/$REALM_NAME/users
```

To export the users with their passwords, you can instead pass the option `-Dkeycloak.migration.action=export` during the keycloak started up:

```
bin/standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export
```

and similarly for import just use `-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import`.

You can read in much more detail about this option on [Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.0/html/server_administration_guide/export_import) and/or in this [blog](https://www.plexx.digital/keycloak-realm-export-import/)